# Display prices in different currencies according to the store selected but for invoices always show prices in AUD in magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, multistore

I have created multistore functionality in Magento 2 and its working fine.
The invoice generated after payment shows price according to the selected store currency, for example, if we select Canada store then generated invoice will show prices in Canadian Dollar, but I want to show prices in default currency i.e AUD
How this can be done?